# Determining if a delta was generated by an undo

Tags: quill

I'm implementing a simple "track changes" type of interface that replaces deleted content with the same content, but highlighted and with a strike-through line. This works fine for normal content the user deletes, but when undoing an insertion, the delta looks the same as a regular user deletion. Is there any way to determine if the delta was from the undo extension? Or is this fundamentally the wrong approach?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Great question - but it's not quite within the guidelines. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for further guidance. This will help prevent your question being downvoted or flagged.

Comment: I read through the help guide and it isn't clear to me which part is not within the guidelines. Are you able to clarify? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the `keyboard` Module to detect here that an `undo` command is done and modify the to-be-applied `Delta` in order to remove its "deleted style".

This pice of code might help you bootstrap your needs:

```
    'undo': {
      key: 90,
      shortKey: true,
      handler: function (range, context) {
        // return true to keep normal Quill behaviour
        // or else return a new Delta that modify context
        console.log(range, context)
        return true
      }
    }
```

Best